# Using eConnect from Excel

Tags: excel, dynamics-gp, econnect

I'm trying to get our database in Dynamics GP updated automatically using eConnect.  I -could- just interact with SQL Server directly using ADO however I like the rollbacks and validation eConnect provides.  I tried to reference the eConnect's dll and serialization dll in Excel's IDE yet I keep getting the error "Can't add reference to the specified file."

How would I go about manipulating eConnect via Excel?

EDIT:  The version of Excel is 2010 and I'm using eConnect 11.

Comment: Are you trying to use VBA in Excel? Is there a reason you do not wish to build a solution with Visual Studio and read from the Excel file?

Comment: I should have updated this ages ago.  I did end up building the solution in Visual Studio not long after this was posted.